# Conditionally filter rows based on mean of a category in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to filter out values of the table based on a grouped column mean.

Eg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2020, 2021, 2020, 2021],
                     'Cars': ['Bentley', 'Toyota',
                           'Aston Martin', 'Nissan'],
                    'Max Speed': [380, 370, 275, 350]})
```

| Year | Cars | Max Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Bentley | 380 |
| 2021 | Toyota | 370 |
| 2020 | Aston Martin | 275 |
| 2021 | Nissan | 350 |

I want to filter rows that have greater than the mean speed of each group.

Here the mean of each group is:

```
df.groupby(['Year']).mean().reset_index()
```

The output of the mean is:

| Year | Max Speed |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 327.5 |
| 2021 | 360.0 |

Eg. therefore, I want to filter the rows in the original table for values greater than the mean of each year.

The expected output will look like:

| Year | Cars | Max Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Bentley | 380 |
| 2021 | Toyota | 370 |

The above table shows the desired output. Both `Bentley` and `Toyota` have greater max speed for the mean of  the respective years.

I am not sure how to access the values with respect to the mean of each group.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transform` to directly create the condition that aligns with the original data frame:

```
df[df['Max Speed'].groupby(df.Year).transform(lambda x: x > x.mean())]

   Year     Cars  Max Speed
0  2020  Bentley        380
1  2021   Toyota        370
```